# IE9 and localStorage not persisting

Tags: html, internet-explorer, local-storage

I am delivering a http: page, to some internal users, who are using IE9, and the page is setting a localStorage value, if it does not exist. On most of those browsers localStorage is working. For a couple of users the localStorage value is set but it does not persist. I have confirmed the localStorage value is set by viewing it through the developer tools console, and have confirmed it does not exist after exiting the browser and then loading the page again.

If it was a code issue it would not work anywhere. A google search has not turned up any answers.
Any ideas on why localStorage would not persist on some IE9 browsers and not others?

Because my users are close by I can visit their computers/browsers and am unable to find any difference between those where localStorage is working and those where it is not. Most work.

Comment: Show us some code. Even though you say that can't be the problem, it won't hurt to show us what you've tried. Also take a look at the issues for localStorage, found [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) (Click "Konwn issues" at the bottom.)

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using to get/set localStorage values?

Comment: This gets it if ( Modernizr.localstorage ) {
  var value = localStorage.getItem(site_key); and this set it

Comment: this sets it `if ( Modernizr.localstorage ) { localStorage.setItem(site_key,login); };